# Labview interprete number as float

Tags: floating-point, type-conversion, labview

I have an issue concerning the datatype I get while reading from a SPS(=PLC) with Labview.

[image: S7 read]

I get a 1D array of 32 bit integer values out of the S7Read_VI which I have to interprete as float values as those values are of type REAL in the SPS.

Labview displays me numbers like this: `1131655987` which is supposed to be 243.7 (when interpreted as float).

The s7Read_VI also offers reads of type REAL itself, but somehow this does not work (some colleagues also noticed that issue).

I am now trying to interprete those numbers (`1131655987`) as floating point numbers in labview and up to now did not come up with a valid solution.

Does andybody have an idea how i can interprete a decimal number as a floating point number? a conversion like SGL shown in the picture, does not make sense i believe, as the numner is already float and just displayed as decimal.

Best regards,
jonnyx

Comment: `1131655987` is a 32 bit integer. If you interpret the value (the 32 bits) as a 32 bit float, you do indeed get `243.7` (I just checked this). I have no idea how you can cast such an integer to float in Labview, though. In Pascal, it would be `IntValue := 1131655987; myFloat := PSingle(@Intvalue)^;`, in C (probably UB, though): `int invalue = 1131655987; float myfloat = *((float *)(void *)&intvalue);`

Comment: yeah, for those who wonder, `1131655987` is `4373B333` in hexadezimal, which you can pass in a float converter you can find online, eg: [link](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754de.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [To Single Precision](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/glang/to_single_precision_float/) node is a cast operator on each element of the array. It does NOT reinterpret the array as an array of single-precision values. If you want to reinterpret the array as single-precision values, use the [Type Cast](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/glang/type_cast/) function and wire in an array of single constant to the type (center) terminal and your array to the x (left-hand) terminal:
[image: TypeCast]

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve my problem was changing the datatype in SPS from REAL to DWORD.

`L     value_REAL*1000 //REAL value like 243.7
RND
T      value_DWORD //now DWORD but accuracy not lost: 243700`

then i just read in my values with LabView and divide them by 1000.

hope that anybody can profit of that.
best regards,
jonnyx